# Isometry group of $3$-sphere

Tags: lie-groups, riemannian-geometry, spheres, homogeneous-spaces, symmetric-spaces

I would like to know how I can prove that $SU(2)$ acts transitively on $S^{3}$. Currently, I want to show that $SU(2)$ is a group of isometries of $S^{3}$.

Comment: Shouldn't the group of isometry be $\text{SO}(4)$?

Comment: I wanted to write that $SU(2)$ is "a" group of isometrie of $S^{3}$ Actually, I would like to show that $SU(2)$ acts transitively on $S^{3}$. Is true?

Comment: Shouldn't the group of isometry be O(4) not SO(4)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider $S^3 = \{(x,y)^t\in\mathbb C^2|\|(x,y)\|=1\}\subset \mathbb C^2$. Then the matrix $A:=\left(\begin{matrix}x&-\overline{y}\\y&\overline x\end{matrix}\right)$ is unitary, has determinant $1$ and $A\cdot(1,0)^t = (x,y)^t$.